# How to start a python script (with Parameters) on another location from desktop

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, operating-system

We are using Ubuntu for OpenERP development, everyday at morning I have to browse to openERP directory from terminal, start the "openerp-server" python file with lots of parameters, and then keep the terminal window open.

Is there a way that I can double click a python file on desktop which will start the following file with its parameters from its own directory ?

The directory I use right now to start the program is "home/username/Projects/openerp_7_0/server/"
after navigating to this path in terminal I enter:

"python openerp-server --addons-path=../addons "

So how can I create a shortcut for this on desktop.

Comment: you can close your terminal window by simply adding a `&` at the end of the command to detach the process...

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want a .desktop launcher?

Comment: or you could just run a cron job...

Comment: I am novice to linux, I have to close the server and restart it several times with different parameters, so any of your method can fulfill this, I don't have any reason not to use it

Comment: related: [How do I start applications automatically on login?](http://askubuntu.com/q/48321/3712) or even better in your case [How do I set up a service?](http://askubuntu.com/q/62729/3712)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than  “double clicking a python file on desktop” you could put a shell script on the desktop (and single click to start, not double click), somewhat as follows.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $HOME/Projects/openerp_7_0/server/
/usr/bin/xterm -e 'python openerp-server --addons-path=../addons; /bin/bash' &
```

(Alternately, say `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` instead of `/usr/bin/xterm`.)  The `; /bin/bash` part may be unnecessary if the openerp-server runs indefinitely.  Include the  `; /bin/bash` part  if you want the terminal to remain (and display any output) when openerp-server finishes; don't include it if you want the  terminal to go away when openerp-server finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Although I would recommend trying to import the python file and then running it that way, I get the feeling that in this case you can't.

So you could try something like this.

```
import os
os.system('python /home/username/Projects/openerp_7_0/server/openerp-server --addons-path=../addons')
```